# Why does C++ allow to compile default copy constructors/assignment operator overloads in classes with pointer members?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

While playing with C++, I noticed that the standard compiler behaviour for assignment operator/object copying is a pain in the butt. While I can understand the default code generation when every member of a class has a defined/default copy/assignment behaviour, I have no idea why the compiler risks generating the code that copies the pointers in a dumb fashion **WITHOUT A SINGLE WARNING**... Why do the compilers decide for the user in this case? Are there really any situations in which default pointer rewriting makes sense at all?

@edit:

Before this gets closed as flamebait, I'd like to point out I didn't mean to rant. As I stated in the comments, I'd also like to ask if there are exceptions to the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Comment: Welcome to C++?

Comment: very hard to follow rule of three?

Comment: There are times when it is useful.  It is much less useful and generally pathological if the destructor deletes any of those pointers.

Comment: Also, is this really a question or a rant?

Comment: Didn't mean to rant. My question also is - are there exceptions to the rule of three?

Comment: well a bald pointer DOES have a defined/default copy/assignment behaviour?

Comment: @Pete: Yeah, I know. The question is why it does.

Comment: It is bourne out of C++'s C heritage.   The default copy of a struct can actually generate block move instructions on some architectures, and it can be extremely useful.

Comment: Exceptions? Sure. In 1995 any short lived collection which indexed long lived data by holding pointers would have been fine. The collection never owned the data which was guaranteed to persis, so it should never delete it. Exceptions in 2013? Not so much, as you damn near never use a pointer.

Comment: @dmckee: What! It's quite standard to return raw pointers to newly-created objects and let the caller take care of the ownership, not sure what you mean by "damn near never use a pointer". (See Chromium's source code for instance.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's quite fine to put naked pointers in classes. The only rule is that it should not outsurvive what it points to, which can be guaranteed pretty easily for e.g. the situation in my answer.

Comment: As a practical example of a class that has a single pointer, see `std::reference_wrapper`. It's a copyable reference, and it's implemented as a single pointer to the thing you're referencing. When you copy of of these, it would be an error to do anything but copy the pointer directly.

Comment: @GManNickG: The fine point here is that that class does *nothing but* hold one pointer. Yes, pointers *are* useful, but they should be constrained to library building blocks. In other words, the *user* should have a `std::reference_wrapper` in their class, and voila, rule of zero etc. etc.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What about my example?

Comment: as Scott Meyers says, "pointers are your enemies" (risk of memory leaks, risk of dangling references, UB); however, as Scott Meyers says, "pointers are your friends" (pointer operations don't throw, etc.). it just depends on what you're programming - just use the right tools for the right purpose

Comment: @KerrekSB: It wouldn't make sense, why would I use it for a tree? A raw pointer does precisely what it needs to.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The children would have a *reference* to their parent... And the parent outlives the children.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why reference? What if I want to swap two nodes?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Then you can swap the reference wrappers, non? (I haven't actually looked that up.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Er, now we're repeating the cycle: Why do I need a reference wrapper in the first place? A raw parent pointer does **precisely** what it needs to, and nothing more. Sure, a reference wrapper *could* work, but it's extra code for zero benefit -- *what's the point*?. My point is that a raw pointer doesn't need to be wrapped in something in order to make sense to be used in a class... it makes quite a bit of sense to use it directly in situations where you guarantee that it won't outlive what it points to.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The reference wrapper costs you *nothing*, and it buys you *semantic power*: It's self-documenting, and it says unmistakably, "someone else owns this". C++ is an expressive language, and there's no reason *not* to make your code unambiguous like that. Someone else who reads this (maybe yourself in a year) will *not* have to look up what this naked pointer means.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's exactly what a raw pointer tells me, I don't know about you. Also I don't see `operator->` declared for a reference wrapper [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)... which kind of defeats its purpose.

Answer (score 3):

> I have no idea why the compiler risks generating the code that copies the pointers in a dumb fashion

There's nothing wrong with classes that have pointers as members, and there's nothing wrong with shallow copying these classes.

Where it gets messy is **resource ownership**.

Dynamic memory allocation is the real culprit here, not having pointer members. And this is just a single, specific case. Others can include locks, streams, connections...

If the memory that's being pointed to isn't owned by the class, it makes no difference. Same with, say, a file stream - you could copy the class and both copies refer to the same stream - but when do you close the stream? Which of the copies closes it? ("which of the copies deletes the memory?")

Having the rule of three in effect makes you think this stuff thoroughly.

All in all - I think it's unrealistic to have warnings everywhere you have a member that's a pointer or stream or whatever other resource you have - there'd be a lot of them, and most are useless.

Answer (score 2):

If the thing being pointed to is not owned by the class in question (not at all uncommon) then a shallow copy is exactly what you want. The compiler can't tell from the class definition what the ownership semantics are so it makes one reasonable guess: *Everything* is shallow-copied.

If your class has ownership semantics for a pointer then you should use the appropriate smart pointer (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, etc) to document the ownership.

Answer (score 1):

A plain (or dumb) pointer *does* have defined copy and assignment behaviour.

If your pointers always indicate ownership, you should be using *smart* pointers. Then, the copy and assignment behaviour is more likely to be (or at least *can be made to be*)  what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just one example:
If you have a tree data structure where each node owns its children, those child pointers would be smart pointers -- but then if you want to hold a pointer to your parent, it'd be a raw pointer, because it's not managing the lifetime of what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

For speed and power.

A non-naive copy can take a long time. If this is a problem for your program, then it is very realistic that you would opt out of the rule of three.

Welcome to C++. You're expected to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do the compilers decide for the user in this case?

The key is that compilers *don't* decide. They make the programmer decide. What do you expect, anyway? A deep copy to be made? That's not exactly possible. Consider the following:

```
// This isn't necessarily "good" code, but it's legal
struct MyStruct
{
    void* p;
    const char* str;
};

MyStruct m1, m2;

m1.p = (void*)&m2;
m1.array = "Hello world!";
m2 = m1; // Now what do you expect to happen?
```

C++ doesn't force you to write good code, so the above is entirely legal. While the above isn't good code, it does show some common use cases of pointers in structures. You can't make a deep copy of `m1` when assigning it to `m2`. It would suck if deep copies were the default behavior, because the above would then fail to compile.